# Weathertron Xl1200 to Nest Thermostat

Tags: thermostat, nest

We have a Trane Weathertron Xl1200 heating pump with the thermostat pictured below and are trying to replace it with our new Nest thermostat. Our old system has a variable speed air handler and we want to make sure that we hooked up the wiring correctly. We have electric heat with emergency backup. Is the wiring we have correct or do we need to change anything? We have the latest version of the Nest thermostat.

**Old Thermostat Wiring**
[image: Old Thermostat wiring]

**New Thermostat Wiring**
[image: New Thermostat Wiring]

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring at the air handler end of your system, as well as the wiring diagram for your system?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the 1 Stage heat Pump with Aux heat and Emergency heat from the [Nest Pro Installer Guide](http://support-assets.nest.com/images/pro-faq/Nest-Pro-Installer-Guide.pdf).

Your diagram is close, but Nest suggests to use Rc (it should internally jump Rc and Rh if necessary) and W -> W2/Aux.

[image: 1 Stage heat Pump with Aux heat and Emergency Heat]

**Note** - variable speed fans are not supported, so proceed at risk.

Comment: see see "second fan speed" on `Y2` and "3rd fan speed" on `*`, isn't that variable speed?

Comment: @Jasen variable fan speed is not supported for this configuration (1 stage heat pump with aux heat and emergency heat). It looks like 2 stage heat pump, and 2 stage heat pump with aux heat are possible, but are obviously configured differently. The dimmed out rows in the table above are descriptions of the other ports/configurations; the bold/darker rows are the ports/descriptions used for this configuration. In this instance, the * port is used for emergency heat.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure your diagram is off.  The Blue in your old system is NOT a common.  The old systems didn't use a common.  I just fixed my old wiring by having an HVAC use a unused wire for common.

It took me years of failure until I dug into the issue again and read about the missing common wire.  Just tossed my old thermostat out yesterday!

BTW - I didn't use the orange or blue on the NEST.  Works fine so far - can't test the A/C until it gets warmer - NEST doesn't allow A/C testing when temp is under 46 degrees.

MB